# Parsing a string to a java LocalTime

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

I have a method that can take in a time string in one of the following formats:

1. `HHmmss` - e.g. `073055` = 07:30:55
2. `HHmm` - e.g. `0730` = 07:30:00
3. `HHmm'H` - e.g. `0730H` = 07:30:30
4. a whitespace or empty string - return null

My current code is as follows:

```
private final static String timeFormatPattern = "HHmmss";
private final static DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timeFormatPattern);

private static LocalTime getLocalTime(String inputTime)
{
    if (inputTime.trim().equals(""))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        char secondsIndicator = inputTime.charAt(4);

        if (secondsIndicator == ('H'))
        {
            // H = 30 seconds
            return LocalTime.parse(inputTime.substring(0, 4) + "30", timeFormatter);
        }
        else if (secondsIndicator == (' '))
        {
            // no H = 00 seconds
            return LocalTime.parse(inputTime.substring(0, 4) + "00", timeFormatter);
        }
        else // specific time provided
        {
            return LocalTime.parse(inputTime,timeFormatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Profiling shows that this method takes 16,439 milliseconds over 7.6 million invocations; and thus is the method with the highest self time in my program's startup.

I have tried splitting this into two methods (one to format the string, and one that simply contains `return LocalTime.parse(formattedTime, timeFormatter);`), to see whether it was the `LocalTime.parse` or my string manipulation that was slow. It turns out that 2/3 of the processing is from `LocalTime.parse`, and the other 1/3 from the string manipulation. This is with half the inputs being of the 4th type (and so not calling the `LocalTime.parse` at all); and half being of the 2nd or 3rd type.

Am I missing a more efficient way of getting the `LocalTime` here?

Comment: Since the `DateTimeFormatter` is thread safe, did you try to reuse it ?

Comment: I didn't; but I have now and it hasn't changed the numbers (still approx. 12,000 ms for the `LocalTime.parse`) - I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your format is relatively constant I would suggest parsing it yourself into hours and minutes and seconds and use the `LocalTime.of` method.  It could look something like this:

```
public static LocalTime getLocalTime(String inputTime){
    if (inputTime.trim().equals(""))
    {
        return null;
    }
    int hour = ((inputTime.charAt(0)-'0')*10)+(inputTime.charAt(1) - '0');
    int minutes = ((inputTime.charAt(2)-'0')*10)+(inputTime.charAt(3)-'0');
    int seconds = 0;
    if(inputTime.length() != 4){
        if(inputTime.charAt(4) == 'H'){
            seconds = 30;
        }else{
            seconds = ((inputTime.charAt(4)-'0')*10)+(inputTime.charAt(5)-'0');
        } 
    }
    return LocalTime.of(hour, minutes, seconds);
}
```